# Does screen size of libGDX-desktop affects Android & iPhone app?

Tags: android, ios, desktop-application, libgdx

I am new to libGDX.I just want to know, does screen size of libgdx-desktop project affects android & iphone project ?
If yes than how ?

```
cfg.width = 1280;
cfg.height = 720;
```

If i change this values to 512 & 512.
Will this affect android & ios performance ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not effect performance but it will make it harder to see as it is a smaller image.

Comment: It means if i put 1280x720 in desk-top project,than screen in mobile will be smaller. ???

Comment: No it WON`T have ANY effect on ANY devices except desktop (since you are changing values in desktop project ONLY).

Comment: thank you.
And is it necessary to use images in powers of 2,like 256x256, 512x512 ,1024x1024......???